# Do reductions (in NP and other classes) follow a linear path?

Tags: np-complete, reductions, np

NP has several complete problems, which reduce to one another. In this sense, they are all "equal" in terms of hardness.

There are other problems in NP that are also "equal" to one another; for example, all the languages containing only a single string are equal. All of these are in P as they are finite.

Let's define a set, $G$, where every entry is a symbol that represents a set of equal problems (in NP). For example, one of the entries can be the set of NP-complete problems. Another can be the set of languages with just a single string.

Is there always an ordering of $G$ where every consecutive entry reduces to the next? This is the sense of the word "linear" I am using in my question's title.

Comment: My intuition says it isn't the case, since I can't see how integer factorization could be reduced to graph isomorphism or vice versa, for example.

Comment: @CommandMaster I think they are linked by the [Hidden Subgroup Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_subgroup_problem) at a high level. But integer factorization isn’t a decision problem, so I am not sure how valid your point is. But yes, I can understand your intuition.

Comment: Integer factorization can be framed as a decision problem (Does N have a non-1 factor less than K)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If P is not equal to NP there exists an infinite number of pairwise incomparable NP intermediate problems.

https://doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(82)90113-2